# Token-based, single-factor LUKS full disk encryption

Tags: linux, encryption, luks, two-factor-authentication

We're building a Linux-based system that will be located at our customer's site and operated by our customer.

We want all data on that system to be encrypted so if it gets stolen the data is still safe.

However, we can't expect our customers to remember and enter a long passphrase at boot ups, and optimally the system will be headless, anyway.

I'm thinking it can't be that hard to have a USB dongle that simply enters a passphrase at the right time during the system boot.  But all I've found so far are solutions for two-factor authentication, still requiring users to enter a password.

What solutions exist for unlocking encryption at boot time without having to enter a password?

Comment: Yubico offers the [YubiHSM](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubihsm/), which is different than YubiKey, and would appear to be what you're looking for.  A motherboard with TPM would also likely work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `cryptsetup` installed, `man crypttab` will be helpful.

`/etc/crypttab` configures how disks are unlocked on boot. Its third field contains path to the key file. It's usually `none`, which means that user should be interactively asked for password. But you can provide a file path as well. A password is equivalent to a file containing this password. You can generate a file full of random bytes, store it on a cheap flash drive and point `crypttab` to use it as a key file.

Please note that this way anyone can plug the "key drive" into a regular PC and copy the key off it.

Here's [how to manually install Ubuntu on an encrypted drive](https://gronostajo.tumblr.com/post/177797691569/install-ubuntu-1804-with-encryption-but-without). It's not exactly what you want, but it contains all necessary steps if you don't want to get too intimate with manuals.

Comment: OK, that sounds promising, but opening the encrypted root fs (with `/etc/crypttab` on it) happens pretty early in the boot process.  Can I mount a flash drive before that happens (and unmount it afterwards)?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what happens under the hood and how `crypttab` interacts with `fstab`, but in the link I've provided I actually unlock a partition that will become `/` with a password and then unlock another partition with a key stored in `/`. This setup is 100% working, so apparently the `fstab` and `crypttab` must be processed simultaneously in some smart way. Probably if you could get an entry for your flash drive into `fstab` it would be mounted before `crypttab` loads a key from it.